# Freemarker template engine and Maven

Tags: java, maven, war, freemarker

I'm using [Freemarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/) in one of my projects. Setting up a project with Freemarker works as expected but now I'm having problems with using this lib in a Maven project. It seems that the templates are not found (I placed them in nearly every folder). The template path is configured in the web.xml:

```
...
<init-param>
   <param-name>TemplatePath</param-name>
   <param-value>/</param-value>
</init-param>
...
```

I start the Maven module via mvn jetty:run.

Where should I place the template files? How can I configure Maven to include these files into the WAR?

[My pom file](http://pastie.org/5365967)

Comment: There's a lot of information missing from your question. Where did you place your templates. How did you set up the Freemarker configuration? What's the exception you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

I would expect to see them in `src/main/resources/WEB-INF`

See also [this interesting blog posting](http://youhenghu.blogspot.com/2012/02/maven-substitution-and-freemarker.html) on Maven/Freemarker interactions.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution:

The template files must be placed in the WEB-INF folder.

web.xml:

```
...
<init-param>
   <param-name>TemplatePath</param-name>
   <param-value>/</param-value>
</init-param>
...
```